# Python: How do I use this code snippet to append text to the next line?

Tags: python, append, shutil

I have made a python based quiz game.
One of my functions reads text from a file and imports it as a dictionary to use as the question/answer base.
I have a file called nmapQuestions.txt and portQuestions.txt.
I intend to continually add pages of questions.
I'm using the below code snippet to make one text file in my directory have ALL the questions in one document. A master quiz if you will.
I have one issue. When this appends 2 files together the second file doesnt start on a new line
it starts at the end of the line of the last file
how do I get this to append to a new line?

```
def master_list():
    outfilename = "zMasterList.txt"

    with open(outfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
        for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
            if filename == outfilename:
                continue
            with open(filename, 'rb') as readfile:
                shutil.copyfileobj(readfile, outfile)
```

OUTPUT:

What is port -T4?: ,intensity

What is port -sS?: ,syn scan

What is port -sA?: ,ack scan

What is port -p?: ,port scan

What is port -sT?: ,tcp scan

What is port -sW?: ,windows scan

What is port -sM?: ,maimon scan

What is port -iL?: ,scan from file

What is port -iR?: ,random scan

What is port -sU?: ,udp scanWhat is port 15?: ,netstat      **<--- 2 on the same line**

What is port 20?: ,ftp data

What is port 21?: ,ftp command

What is port 22?: ,ssh

What is port 23?: ,telnet remote login

What is port 25?: ,smtp

What is port 53?: ,dns

What is port 80?: ,http

What is port 110?: ,post office protocol

What is port 111?: ,rcp bind

Help is definitely appreciated please and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found you could add a new line to the end of the block with the following code:

outfile.write(b"\n")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should make sure your file ends with a newline character.

One solution would be to append the newline first, and then copy the rest of the file.

So you'd only need to add:

```
print(file=outfile)
```

which will add a new line to your `outfile`.

If you want to add 2 lines, do instead:

```
print("\n", file=outfile)
```

Comment: i just don't know where or how to append that new line 

the snippet im using is calling an object so I get an error every time I try a solution like that saying its looking for an obj not a string

Comment: I think the issue is you are opening the file as binary. Also, why did you reject the edit?? It separated your output into a nice more readable format, and removed unnecessary "nice-ities" that don't add any value to the question.

Comment: oops i apologize too be honest it was the first time I saw that pop up and I didn't completely understand what the edit was.